# Confirmation message codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, crud, confirmation

I am setting up a simple CRUD page for my website content and would like to know if codeigniter has any in built functions for displaying confirmation messages.

As I will be giving the user the ability to delete rows from the database I will need a layer of confirmation before they are able to deleted the row.

What is the best method/ suggested way of doing this in codeigniter? I have previously just used javascript, but would like to know if there is another way?

Comment: other javascript :) If you mean confirm dialog boxes, either you redirect your user to a confirmation php page, or javascript is the only alternative (plain, or using AJAX, but it's overkill imho). If you like it more (I do), you can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com), which simplifies your work, giving you even an already set style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [GroceryCRUD](http://www.grocerycrud.com/)? Implementing this might save you some time.

However, your only real options are to use a [javascript confirm() dialogue](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) or to direct the user to an intermediary page (another action in your CRUD controller) which provides the user with confirmation options.

If you're aiming to implement the Javascript solution you might wish to consider creating the delete links with javascript too, that way users without Javascript enabled will not be able to delete. This has it's obvious downsides but will prevent users deleting rows without confirming first.